# unable to get Response from HttpResponse when passing soap object (soap1.2) android?

Tags: android, soap, httpresponse, soap1.2

**Code :**

```
            String response ;
            try {
                final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/myAction";
                final String URL = "MYURL";
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);
                String bodyOut = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:tem=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"
                        + "   <soapenv:Header/>"
                        + "   <soapenv:Body>"
                        ........ MY Data.......
                        + "      </tem:Login>"
                        + "   </soapenv:Body>" + "</soapenv:Envelope>";

                StringEntity se = new StringEntity(bodyOut, HTTP.UTF_8);
                    //StringEntity se = new StringEntity(request1, HTTP.UTF_8); 
                se.setContentType("text/xml");
                httpPost.addHeader("SOAPAction", SOAP_ACTION);
                httpPost.setEntity(se);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity resEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                response = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
                if (response != null) {
                    Log.i("Response", "" + response);// this is not being printed
                    Log.i("test response", "not null");// this is being printed
                }
                else
                    Log.i("Response", "null");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

no exception  but: `Log.i("Response", "" + response);// this is not being printed`

**LogCat:**

```
08-02 19:04:51.929: I/test response(20413): not null
```

Comment: Log `httpResponse.getStatusLine()`. this says that your message cannot be processed.

Comment: @Raghunandan thanks :), you are right i am getting  `HTTP/1.1 400 BadRequest`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087515/wcf-service-using-basichttpbinding-is-still-sending-content-type-text-xml?rq=1. check this close to your error status

Comment: @Raghunandan bad request is coming when i tries `se.setContentType("application/soap+xml");` instead of `se.setContentType("text/xml");`

Comment: check the link 2 comment. i am not sure.

Comment: nice good to know and even better coz your posted solution will help others accept it

Comment: hmm :) thats why i posted the answer !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as its `wsHttpBinding` `WCF service Android`

So I Have Solved this using Following :

```
String METHOD_NAME = "MyMethodName"; 
String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/"; 
String URL = "MyUr;";
String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/MySoapAction"; 



SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

PropertyInfo req = new PropertyInfo();
req.name = "xmlstring";
req.namespace = NAMESPACE;
req.type = String.class;
req.setValue("........ MY Data.......");// without these `tags <soapenv:`
request.addProperty(req);

Element e = new Element();
e.setName("To");
e.setNamespace("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing");
e.addChild(Node.TEXT,"MyUrl");

Element e1 = new Element();
e1.setName("Action");
e1.setNamespace("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing");
e1.addChild(Node.TEXT,
        "http://tempuri.org/SoapAction");

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
        SoapEnvelope.VER12);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.headerOut = new Element[] { e, e1 };
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

String resultData = result.toString();
Log.i("Result", "" + resultData);
```