# call webservice in android with ksoap

Tags: android, web-services

I create wcf with visual studio 2010 and publish on webmaterix 3....
I call this webservice in android app but not running...
this my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>

       <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>

      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

and this my android code:

```
   private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
            private static final String URL = 
                "http://localhost:60977/Service1.svc?singleWsdl";   
  private static final String SOAP_ACTION =     "http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData";
            private static final String METHOD_NAME = "GetData";
             TextView txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,      METHOD_NAME);       
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = 
        new    SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 

                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new    HttpTransportSE(URL);
                name("SS");
                try {
                    name("0");
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                    name("1");
        SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
                    name("2");
                    name(resultsRequestSOAP.toString());
                    name("3");
            txt.setText("Received :" + resultsRequestSOAP.toString());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    txt.setText(e.getMessage());
                    name(e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

when catch run,don't have any messages...

Comment: In AVD to connect to localhost you need to use url http://10.0.2.2/ instead of http://localhost/

Answer (score 0):

**1.** change url to

```
private static final String URL = "http://localhost:60977/Service1.svc";
```

and also check

[getting java.io.IOException: HTTP request failed, HTTP status: 404 in ksoap2 while passing xml data to soap1.2 android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987076/getting-java-io-ioexception-http-request-failed-http-status-404-in-ksoap2-whi)

and

[unable to get Response from HttpResponse when passing soap object (soap1.2) android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18018232/unable-to-get-response-from-httpresponse-when-passing-soap-object-soap1-2-andr)

Answer (score 0):

```
 private static final String URL = 
                "http://localhost:60977/Service1.svc?singleWsdl"; 
            private static final String METHOD_NAME = "GetData";
    final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetData";                  

                       try {
                           SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WebServiceUtil.NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                           SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                           envelope.dotNet = true;                        
                           envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

                           HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(WebServiceUtil.URL);
                           Log.d("URL  :: ", WebServiceUtil.URL);           
                           androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);


                       }
                       catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();

                       }

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

actually, localhost is emulator itself here because the code runs inside the emulator. so you should connect to 10.0.2.2. for more details see 
[Android Emulator Networking](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html) and don't forget the network permissions in the manifest file