# Invoke method in web service asmx

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services, web

I wrote web method in asmx web service

```
List<String> GetData(int id) {...}
```

and then I invoked it by SoapObject in android application 
when I used this code:

```
response = envelope.getResponse();
```

what is the type of response that I should define ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SoapPrimitive` to get Response and then you can convert it to String using `toString()`

```
SoapPrimitive yourRes = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

String yourStringRes = yourRes.toString();
```

**Reference :** https://stackoverflow.com/a/18030085/2398886 and [getting java.io.IOException: HTTP request failed, HTTP status: 404 in ksoap2 while passing xml data to soap1.2 android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17987076/2398886)